# How to get the selected option of dropdown on click of a button in Angular 7

Tags: html, angular

I have a dropdown that contains a few options coming from a loop,I need to get the selected option(not value) on click of a button. I tried with `ngModel` but I was able to get the value, not option. Can anyone please help me? Here is the code below

### app.component.html

```html
<div>
    <select>
        <option *ngFor="let group of groups" value="{{group.id}}">{{group.name}}</option>
    </select>
</div>
<input type="button" (click)="getVal()" value="submit"/>
```

### app.component.ts

```js
import { Component, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent {

    ngOnInit() {

    }

    getVal() {

    }

    groups = [{
        "id": 1,
        "name": "pencils",
        "items": "red pencil"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "rubbers",
        "items": "big rubber"
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "rubbers1",
        "items": "big rubber1"
    }];
}
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "I need to get the selected option(not value)"? Do you want the `name`?

Comment: yes I need the name

Comment: Use the `indexOf()` method to find which option you've selected

Comment: I dint get you I am using value also  <option *ngFor="let group of groups" value="{{group.items}}">{{group.name}}</option>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `ngModel` to bind to the selected value. Since you want to get both `id` and the `name` from the selected option, it would be better if you get the entire object that was selected. You can do this using `ngValue` (Source: [docs](https://angular.io/api/forms/NgSelectOption#properties)).

```html
<select [(ngModel)]="selectedGroup">
    <option *ngFor="let group of groups" [ngValue]="group">{{group.name}}</option>
</select>
```

```js
selectedGroup: any;

getVal() {
    console.log(this.selectedGroup); // returns selected object
    console.log(this.selectedGroup.id); // returns selected option's id
    console.log(this.selectedGroup.name); // returns selected option's name
}
```

Comment: I have value  also  <option *ngFor="let group of groups" value="{{group.items}}">{{group.name}}</option>

Comment: Why are you setting the value to `group.items` if you want the `name`? I'm still not clear on what you want, do you just want the object as a whole with both `items` and `name`?

Comment: In this case its group.items but in our project, value will be there like group.id

Comment: That doesn't answer my question. Can you please be clear on what exactly you want? In the comments on the question, you mentioned you wanted the name, the above answer will give you that. If that's not what you want, let me know exactly what you expect to get in the `getVal` function if you select `pencils` (for example)

Comment: I need name only but when I put value inside  option , its not working showing error I updated my question above. Just I need the  display value of selected option on click a button thats all

Comment: Yes, that is expected behavior because `ngModel` is bound to the `value` and not the display value in the option. I don't understand why you even need the `value` to be set as `group.items` if what you want is the `name`. Just set it to `group.name` or don't set it at all (as you will get `group.name` anyway)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198965/discussion-between-nash11-and-uiappdeveloper).

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

Template:

```
<div>
  <select [(ngModel)]="selectedgroup">
     <option *ngFor="let group of groups">{{group.name}}</option>
  </select>
  </div>
<input type="button" (click)="getVal()" value="submit"/>
```

Typescript:

```
 selectedgroup: any

  getVal() {
    console.log(this.selectedgroup)
    console.log(this.groups.filter(x => x.name == this.selectedgroup)[0].items)
  }
```

See [Stackbiltz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dnsfpb)

Comment: Not working with value  <option *ngFor="let group of groups" value="{{group.items}}">{{group.name}}</option>   throwing error

Comment: I updated my question above

Comment: Try console.log(this.groups.filter(x => x.items == this.selectedgroup)[0].items)

Comment: In setting value, you can directly console the value or the name mentioned

Answer (score 0):

```
        import { Component } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
selector: 'app-pager',
template: `
<div><select (change)="Selected($event)"><option *ngFor="let group of groups" [value]="group.name">{{group.name}}</option></select></div>
<input type="button" (click)="getVal()" value="submit"/>
<h4 [hidden]="hide">the name selected : {{ selected }} OR for click button : {{ button }} </h4>
`
})
export class PagerComponent {

selected : string = '';
button : string = '';

hide : boolean = true;
  Selected(event: any){
    //update the ui
    this.selected = event.target.value;
    this.hide=false;
  }
// or you can use the button :
getVal(){
this.button=this.selected;
}
groups=[
  {
    "name": "select your chois",
    "items": ""
  },
     {
       "name": "pencils",
       "items": "red pencil"
     },
     {
       "name": "rubbers",
       "items": "big rubber"
     },
     {
       "name": "rubbers1",
       "items": "big rubber1"
     }
  ];

}

    //you can give a value groups.name and working with $event
```